# Can anyone identify this French numerical song?

Tags: nombres, paroles-de-chanson

When I was learning a song during French class, it taught us to count to 21. However, I cannot remember the specific numbers and items it listed. Some of the lyrics go like this:

"cinq sandwich, six biscuit, sept giraffe, huit moustache, neuf jambon..."

Can anyone name the song or even put the rest of the rhyme for the other numbers please?

Comment: I've never heard this song, but you forgot the plural form of the nouns.

Comment: And the only occurrence of *cinq sandwich six biscuit* in Google is your message.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps De même en rajoutant les "s"... :)

Comment: Maybe your teacher wrote an updated French version of “The 12 Days of Christmas” and took it up to Epiphany for the extra 9 days! ... Anyway, [“La perdriole”](http://www.acpo.on.ca/claude/charbon/chanson/perdrio3.htm) is an old French song that’s arguably the original inspiration for “The Twelve Days of Christmas” and in the linked version it, similar to the song you seek,  assigns a different item/[gift]  to  each of the 12 months of the year.

Comment: I've never heard it either, but I found a song ["Monsieur Leglouton"](http://www.edu.fi/alexjazoe/harjoituskirja_2/unite_8) which just might be it. Although the giraffe and the moustache part don't match the beginning very well...

Comment: It reminded me very much of a counting rhyme from ["La souris verte"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4MxT1UAlmk), an old French Canadian kids show, but it starts from ten and goes down to one, so it's obviously not the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

« Un deux trois nous irons au bois, quatre cinq six cueillir des cerises, sept huit neuf dans mon panier neuf, dix onze douze elles seront toutes rouges. »

Je ne sais pas si la chanson continue jusqu'à vingt-et-un mais c’est la seule que je connaisse dans le genre.

Answer (score 2):

Il y a :

« 10 moutons, 9 moineaux, 8 marmottes, 7 lapins, 6 canards, 5 fourmis, 4 chats et
3 poussins, 2 belettes et une souris, une souris verte ! » mais je n'ai pas la musique. On retrouve cette comptine dans le générique d'une [vieille série québécoise](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Souris_verte) ainsi que dans un sketche de François Pérusse (entre autres).